# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'utenti' before initialization when i post with postman

Tags: node.js, express

When i post with postman to try and check if the registration works this error appears:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'utenti' before initialization

I'm sure the error is in this part of the code, if i remove async and await the error disappears but they are needed to make the function work

```
router.post("/registrati", async (req, res) => {
  if (await utentiExists(req.body.email)) {
    res.status(409).json({ error: "Già esistente" });
  } else {
    const newutenti = new utenti(req.body);
    newutenti
      .save()
      .then((utenti) => {
        res.status(201).json(utenti);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there a conflict here `const newutenti = new utenti(req.body)`

Can you try changing

```
 newutenti.save().then(utenti=>{
    res.status(201).json(utenti)
```

to

```
 newutenti.save().then(utentiResponse=>{
    res.status(201).json(utentiResponse)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is giving me another error sadly :c (node:5204) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'utenti' before initialization